# Query Spelling Correction

Tags: search, enterprise-search, fast-search

I am trying to create enterprise search. Site admins manage did you mean feature. But i cant open them Sharepoint admin page, they cant add any term correction to taxonamy term store.

[image]

Are there any way to add exclusion or inclusion spelling correction to dictionary? Powershell or sth?

Comment: What cannot you open and is it a term store permission issue?